# Firing CardView's click listener when a RecyclerView in it is clicked

Tags: android

So I have a CardView which has a RecyclerView in it, and I have set an OnClickListener to the CardView. The problem is I want to be able to click anywhere in the CardView but I can't click it inside the RecyclerView. I can only click the part of the CardView that's not part of the RecyclerView. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/phone_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_card_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/phone_numbers"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/phone_card_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/phone_card_title">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You have to implment `setOnClickListner` in ViewHolder view created in recycle view adapter

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid It's the CardView I want to be clicked, not the ViewHolder. thanks for the response btw

Comment: Try putting Card view in linear,relative or frame layout and `setOnClickListner` on cardview parent layout

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your recycler adapater initialize cardview and setonClicklistener for it

example
    Viewholder :

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final CardView cardView ;

   public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.carView);
    }
}


 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}


 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.cardView.setOnClickLister(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //your logic here
        }
   });
}
```